# Find Lowest, Highest, Median and Average Score using findKth

Tags: java, arrays, find, median

For this program, my goal is to...
**Find the Highest, Lowest, Median and Average Score by using findKth
The user must input the numbers (Enter -1 to stop scanner) and they do not know how many there are and if they are sorted**
However, I am seeing some issue with trying to do this.

The findKth method I am provided only takes in an int[]arr, and I cannot find a way to initialize an array to the specific size need for this project.

Could someone suggest a way to to do this?

Below are my test methods and my findKth

```
import java.util.*;
 public class Statistics
  {
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    System.out.print("Enter Scores, -1 to end: ");

    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    String numbers = null;

    while(keyboard.nextInt()!=-1)
    {
        numbers= keyboard.next();
    }


    String[] parts = numbers.split(" ");
    int[] n1 = new int[parts.length];
    for(int n = 0; n < parts.length; n++)
    {
        n1[n] = Integer.parseInt(parts[n]);
    }

    int highest= n1.length-1;
    int lowest=0;
    int median= n1.length/2;

    QuickSort.findKth(n1, highest);
    System.out.println("High: "+n1[highest]);
    QuickSort.findKth(n1, lowest);
    System.out.println("Low: "+n1[lowest]);
    QuickSort.findKth(n1, median);
    System.out.println("Median: "+n1[median]);

}
}

public static void findKth(int[] arr, int k)
{
            findKth(arr, 0, arr.length, k);
}
//Pre:  arr[first]..arr[last-1] contain integers
//  k must be in [first..last-1]
//Post: The elements in arr has been rearranged in such a way that arr[k] now contains the kth
//   largest element
public static void findKth(int[] arr, int first, int last, int k)
{
    int pivotLoc = rearrange(arr, first, last);
        if (pivotLoc==k) return;
        else if (pivotLoc>k) findKth(arr, first, pivotLoc, k);
        else findKth (arr, pivotLoc +1, last, k);
}
```

I've tried different methods such as trying to parse the string for the numbers however I cannot do this as i cannot find a way to properly stop the scanner when the user inputs -1.

Also i have tried using ArrayList, but findKth with ONLY take an int[]arr. So this will not work.

Suggestions? I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a List to collect the input:

```
List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();

input.add(n); // add each number
```

Then to convert to an array after all input:

```
int[] array = input.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

---

Your input loop is buggy. Although out of scope of the question, try a simpler loop, for example:

```
while (true) {
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (n == -1)
        break;
    input.add(n);
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to use findKth to formulate an average as well? Cause what I can tell I would only be able to get the High, Low, and Median values.

Comment: @ConnerK.McPhee the average is just the sum / n. You don't need to know anything about the relative position of elements to calculate that